# Flip animation along an axis (Mirror animation)

Tags: animation, rigging, mirror

Good day!
I created an animation of hitting a punching bag with my right hand (skeleton - humanoid), the question arose: how to reflect the animation (along the X axis) so that now there is a blow with the left hand?

I tried:

- Created an EMPTI element in the center *(0,0,0)*, *made it the parent* of the rig and applied a *scale of -1 on the X-axis*.
  This option will not work because the animation and SKELETON will be reflected (bones will also be mirrored)!
- I've tried copying frames (Ctrl+C) and pasting them by pressing *"Ctrl+Shift + V"*.
  In this case, the animation goes in reverse order.
- The trolls wrote that in the liner you can click on the object and choose to mirror along the X-axis ... it's not funny ...

Please, help!

Comment: When you say that the animation goes in reverse order when copy-pasting, is it going backwards? Or in the wrong direction. You can reverse the frames in the animation sequence if its going backwards to create a "forwards" action.

Comment: "Ctrl+Shift + V" - This action makes the animation in reverse order, this is not the result that is needed to solve my problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all the bones involved in the animation of the right hand with your mouse over the graph editor press A to select all keyframes (make sure none are hidden), press W or right click and choose copy. 
Select all bones from the left hand, make sure they have an f-curve for the selected channels (i.e. insert one keyframe for each channel, loc, rot etc.), select a frame  where you can easily delete the new keyframes.
Go to frame 1 in your animation.
Pres RMB or W and choose paste flipped.

Comment: IDK how to make the symbol for RMB or a key on the keyboard.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I'm not a simple animation, there are movements not only of the arms, but also of the legs and torso ... Is there a universal solution to this problem?

Comment: have you tried it? if you follow the naming convention, it should work with as many bones as you want