# Animation mirroring the wrong direction when pasting reverse

Tags: animation

I'm new to animating and posting in blender. I have been unable to find any information to solve my problem.

I've got a premade armature. It's already set up and named correctly.

I've posed the right arm and right hand. It's great, I'm happy with it. But I want to make a left handed version.

So I go into the dope sheet.
I grab all the keyframes.
I copy them.
I paste them.

And then the side that isn't posed transfers onto the size that is posed.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: Ater]

I cannot find any information how to flip the animations and control what direction copies onto what. It seems to be going left to right and I need it to go right to left.

Because I'm new to posing in Blender I might be looking over some obvious setting somewhere.

Comment: Try this select hand and go in to Key->Copy Keyframes and then select other hand and go Key->Paste Flipped

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192023/flip-animation-along-an-axis-mirror-animation

Comment: Re: Key->Copy Keyframes and then select other hand and go Key->Paste Flipped

No selected F curves. 

The link given by John Eason did not work. I already looked at it before posting mine.